# Error getting JDBC Connection: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am having a problem getting a JDBC connection in an `EJB SessionBean`. The error is:

> org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings.

I thought this happens, because I already have an open connection from a different datasource, so I configured an *XA datasource* to avoid transaction problems, but it doesn't work at all, so I don't know if I am doing something wrong in my code. Here it is:

```
  try 
    {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:11099");
        p.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(p);

        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:/jdbc/etlreportservices");

        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception is thrown while calling `dataSource.getConnection()`.

Comment: Is your EJB anotated with any transaction Anotation?

Comment: The transaction is container-managed

Comment: Thanks tomás you gave me an idea, i changed my transaction manager to be bean-managed and it works perfectly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed my transaction manager to be bean-managed and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, but how? This didn't help me very much. Probably the right answer but not thorough enough.

Comment: It would've been helpful if you added some code or description on how to change your transaction manager to be bean managed.

Comment: Had the same issue and it was because the bean was missing the @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN) annotation.

Answer (score 7):

Can try,
for old Jboss-es:
/server/all/conf/jbossjta-properties.xml

```
<properties depends="arjuna" name="jta">
   <property name="com.arjuna.ats.jta.allowMultipleLastResources" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

for new:
standalone\configuration\standalone.xml (or other what you use)

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.allowMultipleLastResources"   value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this in cases where the tx times out. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Using JBoss 6.0.0, the error message is slightly different:

> Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!

---

As for the reason: A quote from [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/06/javax-ejb-transactionrolledbacklocalexception-could-not-enlist-in-transaction-on-entering-meta-aware-object-error-seen-in-jboss-server-log.html)

> Within the same process, two calls were being made to different non-XA data sources. This is not supported by default on JBoss.

The same site shows a solution which was not applicable for JBoss 6.0.0.

---

The general solution is to change *all* data sources involved in the same transaction into *XA data sources*. Then it works both with *bean managed* and *container managed transactions*. For example, this solution is proposed in a [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/319590/EJB-JEE/java/EJB-enlist-transaction-entering-meta) and in a [JBoss forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/155521) as well.